# Dependency Property mechanism

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

Dependency property are static in nature, so if i create a bool type custom dependency property called as "IsGrayProperty", and implement it on two buttons.
Then if I set the value in btn1 , why it should not be reflected in btn2, as the dependencyproperty is static and their is a .net wrapper property "IsGray"

Comment: Because btn2 is not referencing btn1's attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The static readonly `DependencyProperty` named `IsGrayProperty` is an identifier -- a key value, so to speak. It also contains metadata about the property. It is not the actual property itself. Each `DependencyObject` instance stores its own `DependencyProperty` values internally.

Dependency properties are *semantically* very much like regular instance properties, but they have additional features which let them do things that regular instance properties can't (for example, you can change their metadata at runtime, unlike `Attributes` on regular properties, and you can create attached properties). That's why they exist.

For example, `TextBlock.Text` is a dependency property.

```
//
// Summary:
//     Identifies the System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.Text dependency property.
//
// Returns:
//     The identifier of the System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.Text dependency property.
[CommonDependencyProperty]
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty;
```

And it's got a "regular property" wrapper, too:

```
//
// Summary:
//     Gets or sets the text contents of a System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.
//
// Returns:
//     The text contents of this System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock. Note that all
//     non-text content is stripped out, resulting in a plain text representation
//     of the System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock contents. The default is System.String.Empty.
[Localizability(LocalizationCategory.Text)]
public string Text { get; set; }
```

When you set the `Text` of one `TextBlock`, does every other `TextBlock` share the same text? No, of course not. And if they did, dependency properties would be totally useless.

The `DependencyProperty` parameter to `GetValue` tells the `DependencyObject` which value to retrieve from the dependency object's own internal store of property values; if the value were stored in the `DependencyProperty` itself, you would be querying the `DependencyProperty`, *not* the `DependencyObject`.

```
public void ForExample(TextBlock tb)
{
    var oldtext = tb.GetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty) as String;

    tb.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, "Test value");
}
```

If there is only one global value for `TextBlock.TextProperty`, and it's stored *in* `TextBlock.TextProperty`, why on earth are we calling `GetValue()` and `SetValue()` on some random instance of `TextBlock`? Why get a particular `TextBlock` instance into the act at all?

Instead, we would be calling `TextBlock.TextProperty.SetValue()`.

It's just like a Dictionary:

```
var d1 = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
var d2 = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
var keyValue = "Foo";

d1.Add(keyValue, 32);

Console.WriteLine( d2[keyValue] );
```

What would you expect from `d2[keyValue]`? You would expect *nothing*, because you never gave `d2` a value for `keyValue`. `d1.Add("Foo",32)` does not store the integer `32` in the string `"Foo"`. It stores it in *the dictionary*.

Each dictionary stores its own key values. Each `DependencyObject` stores its own property values. Internally, it probably stores them *in* a `Dictionary`; why not? If the .NET team could write a more efficient way to store key/value pairs than `Dictionary`, they'd have called it `Dictionary`.

When you have an idea about what a language or framework feature means, always ask yourself, "If my idea were true, would the feature be totally useless or massively harmful?" If the answer to that question is "yes", then *you guessed wrong about what the feature means*. That's 100% guaranteed, because language and framework designers and implementers don't habitually waste months of effort designing features which are totally useless ([classes in Perl 5 come close, though](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/73/Trollface.png)).

Comment: Thanks Ed,  yeah you are right, but didn't get how an static property can have different values for different controls, though GetValue,  Setvalue at the end accessing the static readonly property

Comment: It's exactly equivalent to retrieving items from a dictionary: `var foo = new Dictionary<String, Object>(); /* add stuff */ var x = foo["Bar"];`. If you have six different dictionaries, each stores its own personal value for "Bar". The `DependencyProperty` parameter to `GetValue` tells the `DependencyObject` which value to retrieve from its own internal store; if the value were stored in the `DependencyProperty` itself, you would be querying the `DependencyProperty`, *not* the `DependencyObject`.

Answer (score 0):

What is really static, is dependency property descriptor:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsGrayProperty =    
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "IsGray",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(MyButton));
```

The descriptor only contains metadata about the property, and it doesn't contain its value.

The actual property that is used with data binding and accessed from code, is the instance one:

```
public bool IsGray
{
    get
    {
        return (bool)GetValue(IsGrayProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(IsGrayProperty, value);
    }
}
```

as you can see, it delegates get and set to instance methods `GetValue` and `SetValue` of base `DependencyObject`.

Internally, `DependencyObject` maintains an array of entries (in an instance field), where the actual values of its dependency properties are stored. Each instance has its own array, and the actual value resides in one of the entries. As such, it is never shared with other instances. Thus, `SetValue` alters the state of the current button instance, rather than any static state.

The static `IsGrayProperty` descriptor is only used to determine an index into the entry array, perform validations, etc. The fact that `IsGrayProperty` is static, makes it somewhat anti-intuitive to think about, but nevertheless, dependency property values are per instance of dependency object, and are not shared.

Comment: Thanks Felix,By using the GetValue and SetValue, i am accessing the registered static IsGrayproperty, in that case the static property will have only one value at a time, so that should be same for all the control implemented that, but that doesn't happen, I want to know how does dependency property actually works

Comment: No, no, no. By using GetValue and SetValue, you access an instance field that holds array of entries, private to every instance. The IsGrayProperty descriptor is only used to determine an index into the array, perform validations, etc. The actual value read and written by GetValue and SetValue, is at entry in the entry array, and each instance has its own entry array. The fact that IsGrayProperty is static, makes it somewhat anti-intuitive to think about it, but nevertheless, dependency property values are per instance, and are not shared.